# Getting output from another user command

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I'm trying to integrate two pieces of software - one is a Web app, second one is a command line application. The problem is that the CLI application must be run as different user than a Web server. However, I need to retrieve output from the CLI application and pass it to the Web app. I was thinking about using some kind of buffer file, but I'm afraid of crashes when one of the app is not able to read/write from/to the file while other is using it.

I'm sure I've seen once solution similar to this, but I can't recall it. Any help will be valuable. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you could redirect your terminal output to another terminal with the `script` command.

    script -f /dev/ttyX
where ttyX is the terminal you want to copy to.

Answer (score 0):

Run with sudo or set the appropriate owner and the suid bit on your command line application?

Comment: The problem with sudo is that the CLI application accesses another files and starts own processes, so trying to start it with sudo simply doesn't work. Also suiding doesn't work. But still thank you.

Comment: Hmm why wouldn't it work? The child processes will be created with the same user as the CLI application wouldn't they?

Comment: Normally yes, but here in background the application starts virtual machine appliances and they're just crashing when started this way.

Comment: Solved!

I simply forgot about named pipes.

Assuming users are in the same group:

As user 1:

    mkfifo /tmp/apppipe
    ./cli-app.py 2>&1 | tee /tmp/apppipe

As user 2 (later to be read by script on Web server):

    cat /tmp/apppipe

Voila :)